# How to use correctly class and def?

Tags: python-2.7, function, class, tkinter, user-defined-functions

I'm having problem with the variables of a one class going to def in other class.
I want to verify the number of class 'ChoseNumbers' in the def 'number1' in other class, the 'SeaofBTCapp'.
The code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import serial
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)

    self.title("Soft-Starter")
    self.geometry('380x320')

    container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (Home, ChoseNumbers):

        frame = F (container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

    self.show_frame(Home)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

def close(self):
    #port = "COM3"
    #baud = 115200
    #ser = serial.Serial(port, baud)
    #ser.close()
    #if (ser.isOpen() == False):
    #    print ser.name + " is close."
    self.destroy()

def number1(self):
    entrada1 = tk.Entry(self)
    number1 = float(entrada1.get())
    if ((number1 <= 50) & (number1 >= 5)):
        return var1.set(number1)
    else:
        print "Error: Value invalid"


class Home(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.configure(background = '#DCDCDC')
    label = tk.Label(self, text = "Menu", bg = '#DCDCDC', font = LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

    button = tk.Button(self, text = "Escolher valores", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(ChoseNumbers))
    button.pack(side = "top")
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Sair", command = lambda: controller.close())
    button1.pack(side = "top")

class ChoseNumbers(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.configure(background = '#DCDCDC')
    label = tk.Label(self, text = "Escolher valores", bg = '#DCDCDC', font = LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

    var1 = tk.StringVar()
    var2 = tk.StringVar()

    e1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Tempo de subida", bg = 'gray', fg = "white")
    e1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5, fill = tk.X)
    entrada1 = tk.Entry(self)

    entrada1.pack(fill = tk.X, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)

    buttonCheck1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Verificar numero", fg = "black", command = lambda: controller.number1())
    buttonCheck1.pack(side = "top")

    res1 = tk.Label(self, bg = "azure4", fg = "white", textvariable = var1, padx = 5, pady = 5, widt = 3)
    res1.pack()

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))
    button2.pack()

    button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Sair", command = lambda: controller.close())
    button3.pack(side = "top")



app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

And now, the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\screnn-soft\teste_screnn_soft.py", line 86, in <lambda>
buttonCheck1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Verificar numero", fg = "black", command = lambda: controller.number1())
File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\screnn-soft\teste_screnn_soft.py", line 48, in number1
number1 = float(entrada1.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I'm using tkinter to make a little layout for school. I'm not very acquainted with python yet. Please, if you know how resolve this problem, answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the result of `entrada.get()` cannot be parsed as a float by `float(entrada.get())`. Since this is a user entry field, you need to make sure that your users only enter valid floats into this field.